# Malformed packet error during MySQL LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to load a file into an MySQL(v5.1.38) innodb table using PHP's [mysqli::query](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) and a [LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html) query.  The query returns a 'Malformed packet' error code 2027. Any ideas what is wrong?

Here is the target table:

```
CREATE TABLE  `zbroom`.`lee_datareceive` (
  `a` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `b` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `c` varchar(45) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Here is the query:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/path/to/file.txt'
    INTO TABLE lee_datareceive
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t';
```

Here is the file data. Values are tab separated:

```
t1  t2  t3
a   b   c
d   e   f
g   h   i
```

Comment: Does it only fail when used from PHP? Does it work if you run it from the MySQL command line client?

Comment: @Mark Byers: From the commandline it works fine.

Comment: Is php running as an anonymous system user (e.g. `nobody` or `www-data`), or is it running as your username?

Comment: @Tim Post: PHP is running as `nobody`.

Comment: Its likely a permission issue. See Rob's answer and my comment regarding permissions.

Answer (score 0):

same problem. it was permission problem.

shell exec from php:

```
'mysql --user=root --password=zxc db < /stuff.sql'
```

**stuff.sql**

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/stuff.csv' INTO TABLE `stuff` FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
```

Errors with malformed packets.

**Solution:**

```
chmod 777 /stuff.csv
```

PHP is running on its own permission level and mysql isn't getting read access to stuff.csv

You get a cookie if you hate `chmod 777`

Comment: 644 would be adequate :) 777 means the user, group and the whole world can read, write to and execute the file. You almost never, ever want that.

Comment: In my case changing permissions was not adequate. I ended up calling a local Perl script from PHP. Of course, then I had difficulties with piping the results, but that is a different story!