# LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE causes Malformed packet error with mysql2 gem

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, macos, mysql2

I'm trying to issue a LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE query to load some CSV data into a table using the mysql2 gem (0.3.11) under rails 3.1.1:

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.load_csv
    query = "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'test/foo.csv' REPLACE INTO TABLE foos LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' (title)"
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(query)
  end
end
```

(This is a sample app to reproduce the error for [this github issue](https://github.com/brianmario/mysql2/issues/43)). This keeps failing **on OS X (Lion)** with the following error:

```
Mysql2::Error: Malformed packet: LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'test/foo.csv' REPLACE INTO TABLE foos LINES TERMINATED BY '
' (title)
```

Local infile is enabled on the server:

```
mysql> show variables where variable_name like '%local%';
+---------------+-------+
| Variable_name | Value |
+---------------+-------+
| local_infile  | ON    |
+---------------+-------+
```

and on the client via this directive in application.rb:

```
Mysql2::Client.default_query_options[:connect_flags] |= Mysql2::Client::LOCAL_FILES
```

The same LOAD statement works fine from the MySQL client. Changing the DB connection method from socket to TCP/IP makes no difference. MySql is installed via homebrew and the version is

```
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.15, for osx10.7 (i386) using readline 5.1
```

I do NOT get this error running the same code under Linux. It also works if I omit the LOCAL modifier, but that is not an option as the file is in fact local in production and the database server remote. It has nothing to do with file permissions as in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2420140/malformed-packet-error-during-mysql-load-data-local-infile) question.

This is driving me nuts, any insights are greatly appreciated.

Comment: How did you install MySQL on Lion? Through homebrew?

Comment: Yes - edited question accordingly

Comment: Did you explicitly pass `--enable-local-infile` when doing `brew install mysql`? If not, could you try and see if the problem persists?

Comment: Tried that... makes no difference.

Comment: From then on, we know it's a bug in the `mysql2` gem. I had the same and got to use the `mysql` gem instead, but it's band-aid on a broken arm, doesn't fix the root cause. I'm interested if anyone finds one, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this is simply solved by re-installing the mysql2 gem. I think I had installed it with a MySQL version compiled from source, and then later switched to MySQL installed via brew, which led to an incompability in the client code used by the gem. That explains why it did work from the command line client but not when using the gem.

```
gem uninstall mysql2
gem install mysql2
```

Doh...

Comment: I have Mysql version `5.5.19 Source distribution` installed via homebrew. I have upgraded to the latest mysql2 gem as of this writing, version `0.3.11`. I'm using the connection options specified above, but still getting the `Malformed packet (Mysql2::Error)` error when trying to use "load data" through the client in a script. I can run the same commands directly in the mysql client without the error. Any suggestions?

Comment: Works ok on another OS X with Mysql `5.1.41 Source distribution` installed and on an Ubuntu box with Mysql `5.1.41-3ubuntu12.10 (Ubuntu)` installed. So I may roll-back my Mysql version as a workaround, since I can't figure out the "Malformed packet" error.

Comment: There's really no reason do downvote an answer because it doesn't help your particular situation :) good that your rollback worked though.

Comment: To install Mysql 5.1 on OS X with homebrew: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7470529/126688 @Thilo, re-installing the gem doesn't fix the issue.

Comment: Ok finally got it. Using Mysql 5.1 installed with homebrew on OS X as specified in the previous comment, though I think the actual fix was specifying the ARCHFLAGS option when installing the mysql2 gem, and installing mysql2 gem version < 0.3. I installed as follows: `env ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64" gem install --no-rdoc --no-ri mysql2 -v '0.2.18' -- --with-mysql-config=/usr/local/bin/mysql_config`, then I updated my Gemfile with `gem "mysql2", "0.2.18"` and ran `bundle` which set the mysql2 gem version to the correct one. Now "load data" is working.

Answer (score 4):

Issue should be fixed for mysql2 v > 0.3.12b4

It did not work for me using LOCAL_FILE flag, but adding `:local_infile => true` to options did the trick

```
1.9.3p194 :011 > a = Mysql2::Client.new(:username=>'root', :host=>'localhost', :password=>'', :database=>'bhl_indexer', :local_infile => true)
```

https://github.com/brianmario/mysql2/issues/293

Comment: Either for me: `Mysql2::Client.default_query_options[:connect_flags] |= Mysql2::Client::LOCAL_FILES` causing 'Malformed packet error'. But adding :local_infile connection option worked. MySQL v.5.5.40, mysql2 gem v.0.3.16.