# Rails and mysql2 gem malformed packet

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mysql2

My gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
gem 'rails', '4.2.8'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.3.7'
gem 'font-awesome-rails'
gem 'sqlite3'
gem 'mysql2'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0.4'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 1.2'
group :doc do
  gem 'sdoc', require: false
end
```

my database config:

```
default: &default
  adapter: mysql2
  pool: 25
  timeout: 5000
  encoding: utf8

development:
  <<: *default
  host: 127.0.0.1
  database: asteriskcdrdb
  username: root
  password: pwd3lfga
  port: 13306
```

In console I have this error after I launch the console and try to read from a table inside db:

```
Mysql2::Error: Malformed packet
    from /Users/michele/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/mysql2-0.4.6/lib/mysql2/client.rb:89:in `connect'
    from /Users/michele/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/mysql2-0.4.6/lib/mysql2/client.rb:89:in `initialize'
    from /Users/michele/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/activerecord-4.2.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:18:in `new'
```

Comment: Did you tried this solution [1]? Added :local_infile => true as an option. 


[1] https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8790874/load-data-local-infile-causes-malformed-packet-error-with-mysql2-gem

Comment: @tingel2k where put that option? in database.yml?

Comment: tryed by console by this command:
a = Mysql2::Client.new(:username=>'root', :host=>'127.0.0.1', :password=>'pwd3lfga', :database=>'asteriskcdrdb', :local_infile => true, :port=>13306)
Output Of Rails Console: Mysql2::Error: Malformed packet

Comment: Just a curious question: Your mysql port is really 13306?

Comment: @tingel2k do not look to ports or hostname, it's all correct ;)

Comment: Which datatype are you trying to retrieve? A blob for instance could lead to this error message see -> https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_allowed_packet. Also please check the libmysql version on the client and compare it to the server version see -> https://github.com/brianmario/mysql2/issues/715